# Size of Sharepoint 2013 site

Tags: 2013, powershell, site, size

How can I check what is the size of a single site?
exp. `domain/name.of.site`

This site is on root site collection. I know how to get site collection size, but I want size of only particular site.

I tried this command:

```
Get-SPSite http://sps2013 | Select Url, @{Label="Size";Expression={$_.usage.Storage/1MB}}
```

But it is not working.
Any help or suggestion?

Comment: use get-spweb for a specific site/subsite versus get-spsite for the site collection

Comment: giving me 0 as a result. I uploaded a week ago at least 50-100MB.

Comment: I also tried this with 0 result ! and the above command work only for site collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. In **Site Settings** > **Site Collection Administration** > **Storage Metrics**, sites of site collection are shown in list. I found site that I was looking for and its size.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple powershell for this purpose, you can try the below script.

```
 function GetWebSizes ($StartWeb)
{
    $web = Get-SPWeb $StartWeb
    [long]$total = 0
    $total += GetWebSize -Web $web
    $total += GetSubWebSizes -Web $web
    $totalInMb = ($total/1024)/1024
    $totalInMb = "{0:N2}" -f $totalInMb
    $totalInGb = (($total/1024)/1024)/1024
    $totalInGb = "{0:N2}" -f $totalInGb
    write-host "Total size of all sites below" $StartWeb "is" $total "Bytes,"
    write-host "which is" $totalInMb "MB or" $totalInGb "GB"
    $web.Dispose()
}

function GetWebSize ($Web)
{
    [long]$subtotal = 0
    foreach ($folder in $Web.Folders)
    {
        $subtotal += GetFolderSize -Folder $folder
    }
    write-host "Site" $Web.Title "is" $subtotal "KB"
    return $subtotal
}

function GetSubWebSizes ($Web)
{
    [long]$subtotal = 0
    foreach ($subweb in $Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser())
    {
        [long]$webtotal = 0
        foreach ($folder in $subweb.Folders)
        {
            $webtotal += GetFolderSize -Folder $folder
        }
        write-host "Site" $subweb.Title "is" $webtotal "Bytes"
        $subtotal += $webtotal
        $subtotal += GetSubWebSizes -Web $subweb
    }
    return $subtotal
}

function GetFolderSize ($Folder)
{
    [long]$folderSize = 0  
    foreach ($file in $Folder.Files)
    {
        $folderSize += $file.Length;
    }
    foreach ($fd in $Folder.SubFolders)
    {
        $folderSize += GetFolderSize -Folder $fd
    }
    return $folderSize
}
```

Once you have run the script, you can call it with the following PowerShell command:

GetWebSizes -StartWeb

Refrence[enter link description here](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/08/check-size-of-sharepoint-2010-sites.html)

or [Get Size of sub sites PowerShell Script SharePoint 2013](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/get-size-of-sub-sites-powershell-script-sharepoint-2013-or-21059.aspx)

Comment: Thank you on reply. I will check it tomorrow when I get back to office.

Comment: I am getting an error on GetWebSizes -Start URLofSite. 
    The term 'GetWebSizes' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script...

Comment: Did you execute the whole code first? Save the complete code in a ps1 file then run it in powershell window....on the next line run the getwebsizes

Comment: yes. as described on the page you provided.